# Using a keyword(s) to return results

Tags: search, excel-formula, wildcard

I have a workbook what has a tab (Clarity) with a large range of historical information (columns A-IV & c15k rows).

I have created a second tab to search the Clarity information using 1 or more keywords.

Cell `C2` is the keyword input cell and I want the results (using a small subset of 12 of the columns) to be displayed in a separate table.

I have created the following formula in cell `C5` (using ctrl shift enter):

```
{=IFERROR(INDEX(Name,SMALL(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($C$2,Name)),ROW(Name)-ROW(INDEX(Name,1,1))+1),ROWS(C$5:C6))),"")}
```

and then copied this formula down through to cell `C30`. I have then created `VLOOKUP`s in the other 11 columns based on the information in column C.

It seems to work but it creates duplicate records where there aren't in the source data. 
It only searches on one column (column D in the Clarity tab, which I have named "name")
It takes about 10-20 seconds between entering the keyword and getting the results.

If I try and make it search all columns, I get no results - Is there a problem with my formula? Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: Try using `FIND()` instead of `SEARCH()`

Comment: i had tried that, but it doesn't work and becomes case sensitive.

Comment: Sorry, it was the nth small that was throwing the issue. Answer provided below, you can use `FIND()` but you would need to wrap both arguments in `LOWER()` so you are right, `SEARCH()` is better

Answer (score 0):

`=IFERROR(INDEX(Name,SMALL(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($B$2,Name)),ROW(Name)-ROW(INDEX(Name,1))+1),ROW(1:1))),"")`

I updated `ROWS(C$5:C6)` to just reference `ROW(1:1)` so that the first smallest match is found first and the row will update when the formula is dragged down.

[image]

Let's say you want to evaluate against the whole row, make the name manager store the whole concatenated row as each array object.

Comment: when I change the last part to ,ROW(Name)-ROW(INDEX(Name,1))+1),ROWS(1:1))),""), it finds the correct record, but when I drag the formula down, it changes to ROW(2:2), ROW(3:3), etc, but it returns the information for the first record (duplicates it) each time

Comment: @kai did you confirm the formula with Ctrl+Shift+Enter while still in the formula bar to make it an array formula?